# Having Windows Server ISO file and key how install it as a VM on top of Windows Azure VM OS and open its RDP port?

Tags: windows, rdp, azure, windows-server-2012-r2

I Windows Server 2012 R2 ISO file and key. It seems to have unlimited RDP connections allowed (Azure default Windows Server OS provides only 2). how (in as small amount of new software installments as possible) install it as a vm on top of Windows Server 2012 R2 or other Azure VM OS that comes out of the box? How to proxy its RDP port from Azure VM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems to have unlimited RDP connections allowed

This is only the case if you have Remote Desktop Services configured with CALs applied to a Remote Desktop License Server.

> Azure default Windows Server OS provides only 2

This behavior has nothing to do with Azure. This is how all Windows Servers that are not part of a Remote Desktop Services infrastructure behave.

> how (in as small amount of new software installments as possible) install it as a vm on top of Windows Server 2012 R2 or other Azure VM OS that comes out of the box?

You create a VHD on-premesis, preferably within Hyper-V, sysprep it, and upload it to your Azure tenant. From there, you can leverage it through the gallery like any other item there.

> How to proxy its RDP port from Azure VM?

You configure this in the endpoint settings for the VM. Set the public port to AUTO and the private port to 3389 (or whatever you run RDP on - 3389 is the default).

---

All that said, you probably don't need to do this as a generic Windows install does not allow more than 2 RDP connections without proper Remote Desktop Services licensing.